# jQuery getJSON data order varies across browsers

Tags: jquery, getjson

JSON data:

```
  {"2":"Alpha","1":"Beta"}
```

The data format is fixed, i.e. I can't change it, I can only amend the javascript/jQuery code.

```
    $.getJSON("www.myurl.com", function(data) {
        var items = [];
        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
            items.push(key + ', ' + val);
        });
        alert(items);
    });
```

Chrome, IE9, and Opera display:
  1, Beta,2, Alpha

Firefox and Safari display:
  2, Alpha,1, Beta

Question 1: Which is correct?

Question 2: I want the data ordered as in Firefox and Safari. What's the easiest way for me to ensure Chrome, IE9, and Opera produce the same output as Firefox and Safari?

Answer (score 2):

`$.each` operates on javascript arrays (indexes are 0 based integers). The JSON you have shown is not an array. It's an associative array which is what javascript objects are. So:

```
$.getJSON("www.myurl.com", function(data) {
    var items = [];
    for (var prop in data) {
        if (data.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            items.push(prop + ', ' + data[prop]);
        }
    }
    alert(items);
});
```

Or if you want to use `$.each` then use arrays, like this:

```
["Alpha", "Beta"]
```

and then:

```
$.getJSON("www.myurl.com", function(data) {
    var items = [];
    $.each(data, function(index, element))
        items.push(index + ', ' + element);
    }
    alert(items);
});
```

Comment: Using the first option (var prop in data) gives me exactly the same output as my original code.

Comment: The second option is not an option since I cannot change the data.

Comment: @Ian, there is no way to ensure any order if you don't use javascript arrays.

Answer (score 1):

no idea... but you can sort the array after the fact.

given the following output (simulated for testing)

```
var items = ["1, Beta", "2, Alpha"]
```

you can

```
items.sort(function(a,b){ return b.split(",")[0] - a.split(",")[0] })
```

Answer (score 0):

i would rearrange your response to something more like this:

```
[
  {
    "key":"2",
    "value":"Alpha"
  },
  {
    "key":"1",
    "value":"Beta"
  }
]
```

using an array will ensure that the order is preserved.